# ankerl::unordered_dense:set doesn't work correctly with set_difference

Tags: c++

I am writing a solver for a certain graph problem and have following function:

```
void addNewRedNeighbors(int source, int twin) {
        // Merge red and black edges for both source and twin
        ankerl::unordered_dense::set<int> mergedSourceNeighbors(adjListBlack[source]);
        mergedSourceNeighbors.insert(adjListRed[source].begin(), adjListRed[source].end());

        ankerl::unordered_dense::set<int> mergedTwinNeighbors(adjListBlack[twin]);
        mergedTwinNeighbors.insert(adjListRed[twin].begin(), adjListRed[twin].end());

        // Find edges of twin that are not adjacent to source
        ankerl::unordered_dense::set<int> newRedEdges;
        std::set_difference(
            mergedTwinNeighbors.begin(), mergedTwinNeighbors.end(),
            mergedSourceNeighbors.begin(), mergedSourceNeighbors.end(),
            std::inserter(newRedEdges, newRedEdges.begin())
        );

        // Add these edges as red edges for source
        for (int v : newRedEdges) {
            addEdge(source, v, "red");
        }
    }
```

It supposed to find out unique edges for twin vertex and with those produce new red edges with a source vertex. However, I looked into debugger and noticed that when mergedSourceNeighbors contrains {3, 7} and mergedTwinNeighbors contains {11, 7}, I get {11, 7} in newRedEdges, even though it supposed to be {11, 7} - {3,7} = {11}. Is it something special about how `ankerl::unordered_dense::set` works? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Instead of all of this code, did you try a very simple program that uses just `std::set`, with those values hard-coded into them?  If you did, what results did you get?

Comment: Does `ankerl::unordered_dense::set` store its items in order?  That is the requirement for `std::set_difference` to work properly.  [This code using std::set works correctly](https://godbolt.org/z/fb589n1ja).

Comment: Denis: Did the answer resolve the issue or do you want me to clarify anything further?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you, I understand my problem. Probably would need to cast those to sets before computing symmetric difference since I want to utilize complexities of unordered sets somewhere else in the program.

Comment: @DenisKoshelev Great! You're welcome! Yes, you can transform your unordered sets to ordered `std::set`s but measure if the overall result is actually quicker than to _only_ use ordered set. It depends on how often you need to do the transformations of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference):

> Copies the elements from the **sorted range** `[first1, last1)` which are not found in the **sorted range** `[first2, last2)` to the range beginning at `d_first`. The output range is also sorted.

Note: **sorted range** and `ankerl::unordered_dense::set` is not sorted.

`ankerl::unordered_dense::set` is (almost) a drop-in replacement of `std::unordered_set` - which can't be used with `std::set_difference` either.

A workaround is to use a `std::set` (or any sorted container) instead. At least while calculating the difference between the two sets.